# How to have Google Custom Search V2 Search element on master page but result on a Child Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, google-custom-search

I am trying to Implement the Google CSE in my site, I have formatted the look and feel of the Search box and result on google CSE site, now I want to do the following:

- Have the search box on `Master` page so it shows up every where
- Show results on a seperate page say "`search.aspx`", which is a child page of the `Master`
- On Results page the Search box remain where it is in master page. and there is a div for it to show results.

I know we have following elements that can be used.

- `<gcse:search>`
- `<gcse:searchbox>` and `<gcse:searchresults>` A two-column layout
- `<gcse:searchbox-only>` A standalone search box
- `<gcse:searchresults-only>` A standalone block of search results.

But i suppose my requirement can only be met by using a combination of above, but not sure which one.

If any one has done this, can you please guide me what is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

a trick to that is to make a redirect to the search page placing the search on the url, eg something like:

You search everwhere (on master) for the word `test`, and your code if you are not on `search.aspx` is make a redirect to:

```
search.aspx?q=test
```

Now, inside the `search.aspx`, you read the query `q` and place it on the text box that google use to make search and that's all - ah, and one post back to google.

eg the code will looks like:

```
<form action="search.aspx" id="Form1">
  <div>                     
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-XXXXXXXXXX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />

    <input type="text" name="q" size="46" value="<%=Server.HtmlEncode(Current.Request["q"]) %>" />
    <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: are you sure the above html you wrote is for Google CSE V2, as far as i know for redirection you can use '<gcse:searchbox-only resultUrl="your.url.com" queryparametername="query_name">'

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro I just give you an idea, I do not know how you made your search on google - how your google code is, the one I use is like that.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro its just an idea that we have made before 2 years... but we move on with inside indexing, so you may improve it.